# Datadog Exclude City or Local Domain

Tags: datadog

Using datadog, at the top there are tags / attributes. Can i set this to default to everything but X City? I want to exclude users from our company looking at the data.

tried using ! but doesnt work for overall filtering at top of DD dashboard

Answer (score 0):

That would be a feature request I think. when you use a template variable, the value in the variable is injected into the query. So for example you'd see

`$country` have `@geo.country` as the key and you would select a value like `Australia`. Inside the query you would reference `$country` which would dereference to `@geo.country:Australia`.

So if you tried typing `-Australia` you'd end up with `@geo.country:-Australia`. When the correct syntax would be `-@geo.country:Australia`.

The only real hack I can think of here is to create a 'fake' variable called like `$excludeCountry` or something. And in your query you would reference `$excludeCountry.value`. Then in the value of your template variable you would hardcode the full query `-@geo.country:Australia`. Which will then just be injected directly into the query with no syntax issues.

That's not a great experience though. If I needed to do this for some reason and couldn't just hardcode my exclusion without dealing with a variable, I'd probably make a saved view with that query since it's annoying to type out.

---

I'll also mention a good solution that is more scalable is to include an `isEmployee` tag on your RUM data. That's what our company does. So you can add a [Global Context](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/modifying_data_and_context/?tab=npm#global-context) to all your sessions that labels whether that session is from an employee or not, and all your queries will be much simpler in the future.